# cs50/pset1/credit Can't figure out how to use a digit counter without changing the initial variable

Tags: c, counter, cs50

The digit counter works, displaying thhe correct number of digits, however my variable (number) changes from the initial input. I need it to stay the same because I use it later on in he code to test what type of card it is. Here is an example input and output.

/workspaces/cs50/credit/ $ ./credit
Number?
378282246310005
dcounter, 15
num1, 0
number, 12600566272504165

I can't figure out why number changes away from 378282246310005.

Here is the section of code in question...

```
//Asks the user for the card number
long number;
long num1;
    do
    {
        number = get_long("Number?\n");

    }
    while (number < 1 || number > 9999999999999999);

    num1 = number;
//Counts the digits the card has
int dcounter = 0;
    while (num1 != 0)
    {
        num1 /= 10;
        dcounter++;
    }

    printf("dcounter, %i\n", dcounter);
    printf("num1, %lo\n", num1);
    printf("number, %lo\n", number);
```

I want number to stay 378282246310005 after the digit counter runs. I think using the numc variable in the dcounter should do that, but alas it did not. Very new coder and been stuck on this for hours.Could it be a limitation of the long type?

Comment: In general, you should not process credit card numbers as integers; treat them as strings of digits.  However, that's probably tangential to your immediate problem.

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit machine and compiling in 64-bit mode?  Have you checked that `sizeof(long) == 8` (and, to be dreadfully pedantic, that `CHAR_BIT == 8` — a check that is probably not really necessary)?  Have you printed the number before the digit counting loop?  Why not?

Comment: Also, you're printing the outputs in octal with the `%lo` specification — did you really mean to do that?  The octal representation of a number will be different from the decimal value you entered.  You should probably be using `%ld`. (Using `%li` is also legal, but not recommended.  It has a special meaning in a `scanf()` format string, and is included in `printf()` for consistency, but in `printf()` it means "decimal", whereas in `scanf()`, it means "hex or octal or decimal, depending on whether the input starts with `0x` (or `0X`), or just `0`, or with a non-zero (decimal) digit.)

Comment: **Voting to Close** as a stupid typo:  `%lo` instead of `%ld`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `printf` with the `%o` formatter (modified by `l` for *long*).

That prints out numbers in Octal (base-8) format.

Why are you changing from Decimal (base-10) to Octal format?
Do you get the proper output if you use `%ld` (*long decimal integer* format)?

See this code for demonstration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long number = 378282246310005;
    long num1   = number;
    
    //Counts the digits the card has
    int dcounter = 0;
    while (num1 != 0)
    {
        num1 /= 10;
        dcounter++;
    }

    printf("dcounter, %i\n", dcounter);
    printf("num1, %lo\n", num1);
    printf("number (octal), %lo\n", number);
    printf("number (dec), %ld\n", number);
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
dcounter, 15
num1, 0
number (octal), 12600566272504165
number (dec), 378282246310005
```

https://ideone.com/oTEw7B

Comment: Oh, that explains it, I am new to coding and thought %lo just stood for long. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the outputs in octal with the `%lo` specification — did you really mean to do that?  The octal representation of a number will be different from the decimal value you entered.  You should probably be using `%ld`.

Technically, using `%li` with `printf()` is also legal, but it is not recommended.  It has a special meaning in a `scanf()` format string, and is included in `printf()` for consistency with `scanf()`. However, in `printf()`, it just means "decimal", whereas in `scanf()`, it means "hex or octal or decimal, depending on whether the input starts with `0x` (or `0X`), or just `0`, or with a non-zero (decimal) digit.

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long number = 378282246310005L;
    printf("Decimal: %ld\n", number);
    printf("Octal:   %lo\n", number);
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming that you have a 64-bit machine and are compiling a 64-bit executable so `sizeof(long) == 8` (and assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`), the output is:

```
Decimal: 378282246310005
Octal:   12600566272504165
```

Note that it is very often better to treat credit card numbers (and social security numbers, phone numbers, driver's licence numbers, and so on) as character strings rather than integers.